# Ionic Cordova Build prod: Cannot find module “.” - Typescript version >3

Tags: android, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic3

I have updated my ionic project and all dependencies and now when I try to build a --prod android apk I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
at vendor.js:1
at vendor.js:1
at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.js:1)
at e (vendor.js:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:1)
at e (vendor.js:1)
at window.webpackJsonp (vendor.js:1)
at main.js:1
vendor.js:1 Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 57 ms
assets/icon/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I’ve searched and googled so much and the Problem seems to be the typescript version (>3)
But all post are very old (2018) and the only solution was to downgrade Typescript to version 2.6
but this is not a solution for me because I have to use angular >= 7 for Firebase.

Is there a proper solution how I can get this to work???

Ionic Info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.9 (C:\Users\Kumaro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.5
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.1, (and 15 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Program Files\AndroidSDK)
   NodeJS            : v12.13.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.12.0
   OS                : Windows 7
```

Package.js:

```
{
    "name": "Name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": "Name",
    "homepage": "www.blabla.de",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
        "@angular/common": "^7.2.15",
        "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
        "@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
        "@angular/forms": "^7.2.15",
        "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.15",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.15",
        "@ionic-native/app-rate": "^5.17.1",
        "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.17.1",
        "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^5.17.1",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^5.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/device": "^5.17.1",
        "@ionic-native/dialogs": "^5.17.1",
        "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.17.1",
        "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.17.1",
        "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^5.17.1",
        "@ionic-native/market": "^5.17.1",
        "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.17.1",
        "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^5.17.1",
        "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.17.1",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.17.1",
        "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^5.17.1",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.17.1",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
        "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
        "cordova": "^9.0.0",
        "cordova-android": "^7.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
        "cordova-plugin-apprate": "^1.5.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
        "cordova-plugin-market": "^1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
        "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
        "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.6.2",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^4.0.0",
        "ionic-angular": "3.9.5",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.29"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.2",
        "@ionic/lab": "^2.0.16",
        "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "^0.7.3",
        "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^2.0.5",
        "typescript": "^3.1.1"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
            "cordova-plugin-apprate": {},
            "cordova-plugin-market": {},
            "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
            "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
            "cordova-plugin-background-mode": {},
            "cordova-plugin-dialogs": {},
            "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android"
        ]
    }
```

I hope anybody can help :(

Comment: Is this Ionic 3 app?

Comment: You are right it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly You need to set the correct tags on your question. Now I have done that. i.e. `Ionic 3`

Your update is wrong. Ionic 3 doesn't support `Angular 7` and `RxJS 6 +`

You need to follow this official app to update it to the correct versions.

Official Ionic 3 app: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/blob/v3/package.json#L16

OR ***Migrating from Ionic 3.0 to Ionic 4.0:*** https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration

Comment: Sorry for the mistake! So I have to downgrade to older versions or migrate my app to ionic 4? Right? But everything is working fine instead of typescript. So angular and rxjs 6 are not the problem :)

Comment: It is up to you. Migrating from 3 to 4 is not a simple task. You can see the link above for that. But the future is Ionic 4.